# Execute method in fragment before ad it to backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have multiple fragments  and I can switch between them, my problem is on how can I execute a method in a fragment before it goes to backstack.
If I execute some method in fragment's `OnPause()` or `OnStop()` my activity is closing with all fragments instantly. The code to switch from one fragment to another is:

```
  public void switchFrgFromFrg(Fragment fragment, String tag, boolean isAddedToBackStack, int idContainer) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(idContainer, fragment, tag);
    if (isAddedToBackStack) {
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
   }
```

Any help is apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fragment `onResume()` and `onPause()` will be called only when the Activity `onResume()` or `onPause()` that holds it is called. They are tightly coupled to the Activity, that's why your fragment is closing. I sugest you ti implement a back key listener as:

```
 private void doBackActionListener(View view){
    view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    view.requestFocus();

    view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    //execute code

                    //then do standart go back  action
                    getActivity().onBackPressed();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

You will cal this in your `onCreateView()` and pass inflated view as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I execute a method in a fragment before it goes to `backstack`

When you fragment is visible you can execute as many methods as you want

> If I execute some method in fragment's `OnPause()` or `OnStop()` my activity is closing with all fragments instantly.

That's because some `Exception` is arising in your code. It is better to show your console (Log messages) in your question.

Comment: I am trying to execute an Retrofit 2 async call, it runs without any exception but my activity is closing

Comment: You need to update your code with piece of that code which is causing the issue